# Error al Instalar Android Studio en MacOS Catalina

Tags: java, android, android-studio, macos, instalacion

Llevo dos días intentando instalar Android Studio en Mac OS Catalina después de hacer una instalación limpia.

Pero tengo estos Errores:

Primero al intentar recompilar un Proyecto que tengo echo y ahora me pone esto:

```
18:16   Emulator: emulator: WARNING: EmulatorService.cpp:448: Cannot find certfile: /Users/user/.android/emulator-grpc.cer security will be disabled.

18:16   Emulator: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554
```

Y ya probé a instalarlo 3 o 4 veces, también java y gradle
De que podría ser?

Comment: El error es al instalar Android Studio o al compilar un proyecto?

Comment: Es problable que algun programa que use android studio esté en 32bits??? recuerda que con catalina solo soporta programas de 64bits

Comment: El error ese es al intentar correr la app en un emulador, ya que el emulador que tenía antes lo borré a reinstalar.